# Angular page, XPath not finding text

Tags: angular, selenium, xpath

We have an Angular page that generates a lot of comment blocks into the page.
When trying to find text using xPath (for Selenium) it cannot find it.

```
<li>
   <span class="os">Order status is </span>
   Sent 
   <span class="ng-star-inserted"> (<!----><!---->Awaiting confirmation) </span><!---->
</li>
```

`//*[text()=' (']` finds it, but `//*[text()='Awaiting confirmation']` or `//*[.,'Awaiting confirmation']` or `//*[contains(text(),'Awaiting confirmation')]` do not.

We need to make sure "Sent (Awaiting confirmation)" or at least "Awaiting confirmation" is on the page.

Any advice would be appreciated

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks for the input, but unfortunately none of them worked.
Probably because of the comments entries.

In the end I created another function that receives xPath instead of just a name.
Someone posted a working solution, but deleted it again.

So in my case the only thing that worked was `//li[contains(.,'Sent') and contains(.,'Awaiting confirmation')]` - Thanks to whoever posted it.

Answer (score 2):

```
//*[text()[contains(.,"Awaiting confirmation")]]
```

### Try this , this will search for element that contains the text Awaiting confirmation as you want (In your case span